# Cannot Animate Activity Indicator through Storyboard

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview, launch-screen

I am actually using activity indicator in LaunchScreen
But cannot animate through storyboard using Attributes inspector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LaunchScreen` is a static image shown by the iOS until the application is launched. To show the activity indicator or in fact to show any UI changes after the application launch you need to add another viewcontroller which is shown as a first view controller with the same image in the background as a splash screen and add other UI components.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do any animations with `LaunchScreen` storyboard vc as it's displayed statically when the app is launched , you need to create a splash vc , add the `activtyIndicator` to it then animate